# Show a single item in a dropdown menu

Tags: angular, ionic2

i am trying to create a filter with a list of items, on clicking on the list header a drop down with check box appears, i have used ngIf to hide and show it works fine but, What i need is if i click on the 1st item in the list only the check box in that 1st item should drop down not for other items.

```
  <ion-grid>
     <ion-row>
        <ion-label>color</ion-label>
        <ion-icon name="ios-arrow-forward" (click)="arrowdown()" *ngIf="dropdown"></ion-icon>
            <ion-icon name="ios-arrow-down" (click)="arrowRight()" *ngIf="!dropdown"></ion-icon>
        </ion-row>
        <ion-row >
           <ion-col *ngIf="!dropdown">
            <ion-item  *ngFor=" let item of colors; let i=index ">
                   <ion-label>{{item}}</ion-label>
                    <ion-checkbox color="dark"></ion-checkbox>
             </ion-item>  
          </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
     </ion-grid>

    <ion-grid>
        <ion-row>
           <ion-label>sex</ion-label>
           <ion-icon name="ios-arrow-forward" (click)="arrowdown()" *ngIf="dropdown"></ion-icon>
            <ion-icon name="ios-arrow-down" (click)="arrowRight()" *ngIf="!dropdown"></ion-icon>
        </ion-row>
        <ion-row >
           <ion-col *ngIf="!dropdown">
             <ion-item  *ngFor=" let item of sexs; let i=index ">
                <ion-label>{{item}}</ion-label>
                <ion-checkbox color="dark"></ion-checkbox>
             </ion-item>  
            </ion-col>
         </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
```

In my ts file

```
dropdown: boolean = true;
 colors: any = [];
 sexs: any = [];


 arrowdown(){
        this.dropdown = false;
        this.fileter(); 
    }
    arrowRight(){
        this.dropdown = true;
        this.fileter(); 
    }
```

Currently i used the hide, show property to all item in the grid, I need when i click on the color the check box should dropdown below color not in other items like sex,family

[image]

Comment: you are using the same `dropdown` boolean variable and the same function in both checkboxes for both.. Use different ones.

Comment: consider i have 10 different items in checkbox how do i control it

Comment: if I understand your use case correctly, you could use `ion-select` with `multiple` set to true.. http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/select/Select/ that way you dont have to track with boolean or click functions

Comment: Check out image @suraj

Comment: yes, you have to use 10 different variables for 10 different items. Or you can use boolean array for that like `dropdown:boolean[]=[true,true]` and in html bind like `*ngIf=dropdown[1]`

Comment: used ion-select with multiple set to true but when i use it like this it comes out as an alert and ask to choose value, How do i get a list in dropdown format below the item label